# Find the common sub string using list comprehension

Tags: python, list

I have a code below to find the common substring. How to convert to using list comprehension.Is there enhance in the code can be done

```
def commonSubstring(a, b):
    m = list(zip(a,b))
    for i, j in m:
        flag = False
        for a in i:
            if a in j:
                print("YES")
                flag = True
                break
        if not flag:
            print("NO")
commonSubstring(['ab', 'bd'], ['am','cc'])
```

My Out and Expected out

`YES
NO`

Comment: So... I'm not sure I understand what you want to do, but the output is `YES` because the letter `a` is in `am` (which what is checked by your code at the first iteration of your loop) and because you break the loop after having printed `YES`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def commonSubstring(a, b):
  return ["YES" if set(i).intersection(j) else "NO" for i, j in zip(a, b)]

print(*commonSubstring(['ab', 'bd'], ['am','cc']), sep="\n")
```

**Output**

```
YES
NO
```